# Why does this Capture Attribute node transfers zeros to another geometry?

Tags: geometry-nodes

In related picture I want to sample positions of a cone's verticies and transfer them to cube's verticies' positions. Why are all transferred positions (0, 0, 0)?

[image: Geometry nodes]

Comment: Hello and welcome to Blender.SE! If you want to transfer values from one geometry to another, you need `Sample Nearest` and `Sample Index`.And I wonder what you actually want to achieve, because I don't quite understand the sense of your intention. What exactly are you planning?

Comment: Hello. My initial intent was creating 3-corner faces from randomly scattered points by creating `Mesh Circle`s and then transfering positions from 3 points to the circle's points using `Capture Attribute` and `Set Position`. But it didn't work out so I just started messing around and created this simple "test".